# How to set NSString containing %%@% with %@ a value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I would like to set a NSString as `@"SELECT a, b FROM abc WHERE c LIKE %MYVALUE%"`.
So I init my `NSString` with `initWithFormat` like that:

```
NSString * query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT a, b FROM abcd WHERE c LIKE %%@%%", searchBar.text];
```

But it doesn't work of course.

**How do I build this kind of query?**

Comment: [Typo questions are too localized.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Comment: You should use "prepared statements" to avoid SQL injection attacks (see http://xkcd.com/327/ !).

Comment: This is not exactly a typo question. This question is about not knowing how to escape special characters in a query. Don't know where that falls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `%%` to include a `%` in the string.

```
@"SELECT a, b FROM abcd WHERE c LIKE '%%%@%%'"
```

Your current string (`%%@%%`) will be interpreted as percentage sign, at sign, percentage sign (`%@%`)

Comment: The `LIKE` value needs to be in single quotes too.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you need to mark the start and end of the `LIKE` condition with `'`?

So `initWithFormat:@"SELECT a, b FROM abcd WHERE c LIKE '%%%@%%'", searchBar.text];`

Comment: Better yet is to use `... LIKE ?` and then use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to bind the value.

Answer (score 0):

With your current %%@%%, the first % escapes the second %, then you just have an @ and then you have another % escaping another %, resulting in %@%

What you really want is %%@%, but you need to escape the % with a % so you get `%%%@%%` resulting in `%searchBar.Text%`